# Search within subdatasets in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, select, group-by

I want to search within each subdataset in `df`:

`df`:

```
                        id      timestamp               data    gradient        Start
timestamp                                       
2020-01-15 06:12:49.213 40250   2020-01-15 06:12:49.213 20.0    0.00373         NaN 
2020-01-15 06:12:49.313 40251   2020-01-15 06:12:49.313 19.5    0.00354         0.0 
2020-01-15 08:05:10.083 40256   2020-01-15 08:05:10.083 20.0    0.00020         1.0 
2020-01-15 08:05:10.183 40257   2020-01-15 08:05:10.183 20.5    -0.00440        0.0
                            ...
2020-01-31 09:01:50.993 40310   2020-01-31 09:01:50.993 21.0    0.55473         1.0
2020-01-31 09:01:51.093 40311   2020-01-31 09:01:51.093 21.5    0.00589         0.0
                            ...
```

A sub-dataset starts with `Start==1` and ends with next `Start==1`. I want to search within each sub-dataset time until when `gradient >0.0003` ** but not inclusive**(`end_time`) from `start==1`(`start_time`), then calculate the average of `data`, to obtain a table like this:

```
start_time               end_time                   Average
2020-01-15 08:05:10.083  2020-01-15 08:05:23.273    35(for example)
...
```

---

Edit:
Reproducible dataframe:

```
d = {'timestamp':["2020-01-15 06:12:49.213", "2020-01-15 06:12:49.313", "2020-01-15 08:05:10.083", "2020-01-15 08:05:10.183", "2020-01-15 09:01:50.993", "2020-01-15 09:01:51.093", "2020-01-15 09:51:01.890", "2020-01-15 09:51:01.990", "2020-01-15 10:40:59.657", "2020-01-15 10:40:59.757", "2020-01-15 10:42:55.693", "2020-01-15 10:42:55.793", "2020-01-15 10:45:35.767", "2020-01-15 10:45:35.867", "2020-01-15 10:45:46.770", "2020-01-15 10:45:46.870", "2020-01-15 10:47:19.783", "2020-01-15 10:47:19.883", "2020-01-15 10:47:22.787"],
'data': [20.0, 19.5, 20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5, 22.0, 22.5, 23.0, 23.5, 23.0, 22.5, 23.0, 23.5, 24.0, 24.5, 25.0, 25.5, 26], 
'gradient': [NaN, NaN, 0.000000, 0.000148, 0.000294, 0.000294, 0.000339, 0.000339, 0.000334, 0.000334, 0.000000, -0.008618, 0.000000, 0.006247, 0.090884, 0.090884, 0.010751, 0.010751, 0.332889],
'Start': [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Expected output for reproducible dataframe:

```
start_time               end_time                   Average
2020-01-15 08:05:10.083  2020-01-15 09:01:51.093    20.75  = average of (20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5)
2020-01-15 10:45:35.767  2020-01-15 10:45:35.767    23.00  = average of (23.0)
```

Comment: Is possible change data for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I think at least one group matching conditions.

Comment: @jezrael please see edited question. Is that oaky? Please also note that I changed the threshold to `0.0003` to suit the reproducible dataframe. Thank you.

Comment: I think `mcve`, it means 5 - 8 rows. What rows are used for mean from edited dataframe? What is expected output?

Comment: avg is cout inclusive or not?

Comment: @jezrael mean is calculate using rows from `Start==1`(eg.`2020-01-15 08:05:10.083`)  until `gradient >0.003`(eg. `2020-01-15 09:51:01.890`) **but not inclusive**, sorry I didn't specify clearly in the question.

Comment: OK, please give me some time. Not problem ;)

Comment: @jezrael sorry it's wrong, it shouldn't be included, I'll edit the quesiton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df['g'] = df['Start'].cumsum()
df['m'] = df['gradient'].gt(0.0003)

#filter first group - rows before first 1
df1 = df[df['g'].ne(0)].copy()

#filter rows to first True in column m
df1 = df1[df1.groupby('g')['m'].cumsum().eq(0)]

#named aggregation
df2 = df1.groupby('g').agg(start_time=('timestamp','first'),
                           end_time=('timestamp','last'),
                           Average=('data','mean')).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
                start_time                 end_time  Average
0  2020-01-15 08:05:10.083  2020-01-15 09:01:51.093    20.75
1  2020-01-15 10:45:35.767  2020-01-15 10:45:35.767    23.00
```

Comment: Hi, I just added the expected output for the reproducible dataframe. I think the average is exclusive (>).

Comment: @nilsinelabore - answer was edited, please check it.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to change to `greater than 0.0003 and less than 0`? Btw, would you be able to add the solution for a similar sub-question, where we can find the "average data from the `Start==1` time to 30 seconds later"?Sorry I understand it's a different question, I can ask another question if that's fine..

Comment: @nilsinelabore - `greater than 0.0003 and less than 0` is correct? Because if greater like `0.0003` not exist number less like `0`. Or there is OR?

Comment: Sorry it should be `greater than - 0.0003 and less than 0`.

Comment: Ok I got it.  For first `df['m'] = df['gradient'].gt(0.0003)` change to `df['m'] = df['gradient'].between(-0.0003, 0, inclusive=False)`

Comment: I noticed that the the `end_time` and the next `start_time` are all back to back? Is it supposed to be this way?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - `are all back to back?` What so you think?

Comment: I observed that the end-time is followed by the next start_time in the output table(ie. they are adjacent rows in the original `df`). That means it covers all the data in `df`. I think it may be that the interval I set for `gradient` is too wide?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - So some data related issue?

Comment: Yeah I think that makes sense. Please allow me to double  check the data. Thank you so much for your help :)